# copy YUV video frames from one buffer to another in Gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I am extremely new to Gstreamer. I am writing a plugin to reduce the height of a YUV video by 2. I get a segmentation fault when I try to copy data from the buf(argument to chain) to another buffer in the _chain() function as follows :

GstBuffer *buffer;

glong size;

size = GST_BUFFER_SIZE(buf);

buffer = gst_buffer_new ();

GST_BUFFER_SIZE (buffer) = size;

GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA (buffer) = g_malloc (size);

GST_BUFFER_DATA (buffer) = GST_BUFFER_MALLOCDATA (buffer);

memcpy(buffer,buf,size);

Kindly help a newbie :)
Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You are copying over the buffer object! Try using:

```
buffer = gst_buffer_new_and_alloc(size);
memcpy(GST_BUFFER_DATA(buffer),GST_BUFFER_DATA(buf),size);
```

You could also do

```
buffer = gst_buffer_copy(buf);
GST_BUFFER_SIZE (buffer) = size;
```